# Flow rate and Pressure relation

Tags: fluid-mechanics

I have a system involving a tank of nitrogen gas inflating a balloon, the tank pressure drops from about 4500 psi to 120 psi, inflating the balloon to 20 psi. How can I calculate the average flow rate (both mass and volumetric), and the time it takes the balloon to reach 20 psi. From my amateur standpoint, Bernoulli's equation seem to involve the pressure drop rather than the driving pressure relative to flow velocity. Can anyone help with that?

Comment: Have a look here, a simple google search : https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_to_calculate_flow_rate_of_compressed_gas

Comment: The answers here may be useful : https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/25985/10902

Comment: That's extremely helpful Mike. Thanks a bunch.